Rebinding Direct Input joystick keys
A game I want to play reads joystick/gamepad input, but doesn't support key rebinding. Whenever Joy6 is pressed, game fastforwards text, and I want this key to increase system volume instead. Autohotkey is capable of hooking joystick keys, but not of blocking them. Is it possible to maybe hijack dinput.dll somehow, to block this game from receiving joystick input? Doesn't look like this game uses any joystick related functions from winmm.dll.
Game I want to play is NUKITASHI, or 抜きゲーみたいな島に住んでる貧乳はどうすりゃいいですか, if that's of any relevance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

These products can help in translating joystick buttons to other keys.
Together with AutoHotkey, this can be a complete solution.

UCR
JoyToKey

